# Diffeomorphisms and Lipschitz Condition

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$. and let g: $A \to \Bbb R^n$ be locally Lipschitz. 
>   Show that if the subset $E$ of $A$ has measure zero in $\mathbb R^n$, then $g(E)$ has measure zero in $\mathbb R^n$

Many Thanks.

Comment: Let epsilon and delta > 0 and show that if a set S has a measure zero in R^n, then S can be covered by countably many closed cubes, each with width less than delta. Also, then we can select C as a closed cube contained in A s.t. Dg(x) <= M for x an elemeent of the close cube C. We then show that g(E) has measure zero

Comment: Like I can take a seqquence of compact sets whose unioon is A, s.t. C sub i is a subset of Ci+1.

Comment: but I need help in proceeding

Comment: Since $A^c$ is closed, you can define $C_i=\overline{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | dist(x,A^c)>\frac{1}{i} \} \cap B(0,i)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E\subset A$ have measure zero and put $C_k\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an increasing sequence of compacts such that
$$
A\subset \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty C_k.
$$
Let us denote $E_k = E\cap C_k$ and a measure on $\mathbb R^n$ through $\mu$. If we show that $\mu (g(E_k)) = 0$ for all $k$ it clearly means that $\mu(g(E)) = 0$.

Since $E_k$ has a measure zero as a subset of $E$, for any $\delta>0$ there is a cover of $E_k$ with open balls $\{B(x_i,r_i)\}_{i=1}^m$ such that their total measure does not exceed $\delta$. So,
$$
E_k\subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m B(x_i,r_i).
$$
Note that if $x\in E_k$ then there is $i = 1,\dots,m$ such that $|x-x_i|\leq r_i$. As a result, for any $y\in g(E_k)$ there is $i = 1,\dots,m$ such that $|y-g(x_i)|\leq \lambda_k r_i$ where $\lambda_k$ is  a Lipschitz constant for $g$ restricted to $E_k$. As a result,
$$
\mu(g(E_k))\leq\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m B(g(x_i),\lambda_k r_i)\right)\leq \lambda^n_k \delta.
$$
Since $\delta$ is arbitrary, we obtain that $\mu(g(E_k)) = 0$ and hence $\mu(g(E)) = 0$.

Comment: I think you need $\lambda_k^n$ in the penultimate line.

Comment: @savick01: thanks, you're right

Comment: Sorry for my late follow-up, but how does $E_k$ being of measure zero imply there is a _finite_ open cover with the property above? Couldn't it be just countably infinite?

Comment: @Spring It was some time but they are compact sets, so measure zero does not imply finite cover, the compactness does

Comment: @Ilya, but why is $E_k$ compact? If we take $E\subset\Bbb Q^n-$ a countable set, therefore, of measure $0$ in $\Bbb R^n,$ and the cube $C_k=[0,1]^n,$ $E_k=E\cap C_k$ is of measure $0,$ but not compact as it is not closed.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. They are pre-compact, so you can take a cover of their closure I guess. The open cover of $E_k$ seems to be that of its closure as well if I'm not mistaken