# do all diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserve measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be the Cantor Lebesgue function and $g(x)=x+f(x)$. Then $g(x)$ is a homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$. But $g(x)$ maps a non-measurable set to a measurable set. Hence homeomorphism does not preserve measurable sets.

For an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it preserves Lebesgue measure and maps measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to measurable subsets.

How about diffeomorphisms? Given a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, does it map measurable subsets to mesurable subsets?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112815/diffeomorphisms-and-lipschitz-condition seems like it could be of use to you.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Every Lebesgue measurable set is the union of an $F_\sigma$ and a null set. $F_\sigma$s are preserved under all homeomorphisms, and as the linked question shows, diffeomorphisms - which are locally Lipschitz - map null sets to null sets.